# Trouble Importing Data into mySql Workbench with Sql File

Tags: sql, database, import, field, mysql-workbench

First time poster here so I'll try to be as specific as I can.If I'm in any way vague just tell me.

So I'm trying to import these .sql files into mySQL workbench so I can use that Database for a project that I'm currently working on for school. Don't worry it's not an homework. I just want that to work so I can actually do the homework.

Here is an example of the first Table in the file:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema h16_equipe_2
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema h16_equipe_2
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `h16_equipe_2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `h16_equipe_2` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `h16_equipe_2`.`roles`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `h16_equipe_2`.`roles` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `h16_equipe_2`.`roles` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`roles_creation_ts` TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
`roles_modification_ts` TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
`roles_creation_user` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`roles_modification_user` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`uuid` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
`deleted_on_ts` TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
`archived_on_ts` TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
`note` VARCHAR(254) NULL,
`role` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`system` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `uuid_UNIQUE` (`uuid` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So I have no error what so ever when I import that file but when I import it, I have everything but the fields inside the tables

And when I try to edit them this message pops-up

[MysqlWorkbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gxN9.png)

If I click either options I get my table but no fields ... Any solution ?

Comment: You don't import that file, you execute it. It's a script. Did you tables get built? Do you have data for it or do you need an empty db?

Comment: okay so where can i run this query ? yes the tables were built but they are empty and also yes i actually have another .sql file that has all of my data

Comment: if the tables are created, then you don't need to do it again. from the command line you can dump the data in with; mysql databaseName < dataFile  You may need to add security params; mysql -uNAME -pPASS dbName < dataFile

Comment: yes but the tables are created but they are empty there is no data inside the tables and my sql file is supposed to create those things like role and note in this case

Comment: not data sorry i mean fields my bad

Comment: re-run the script then, it will delete the partially created tables and start over.

Comment: I think i found out the problem ... i had the client version of MySql workbench. and no server so i made it work by downloading the Server version of it  Thanks for your help anyway. It's mostly because i did not have a connection